# Has Kubuntu 20.04.3 finally gotten Bluetooth right?

Tags: kubuntu, bluetooth

I really want a system that gets Bluetooth right. I've been suffering through the instability of Bluetooth in version 20.04, with a collection of fixes that work for some people but not others (and in particular not for me).  I've read that these problems have been fixed in the 21.xx releases. I'd like to have a release that will be around for a while, but I want to get it *now*. So should I get 20.04.3, 21.04 or 21.10?

Answers to this question will probably not be useful in a couple of months.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include more details? I have been using Kubuntu LTS as a daily driver since the 18.04 LTS release and currently use 20.04 LTS and have never had any problems with any of Bluetooth devices, which has included speakers, phones, mice, keyboards, game controllers.  Your question doesn't include any details about a problem and can't be reproduced, so I don't see how we could answer.

Comment: curious thing: i have 20.04 and BT service works correctly (audio, data sharing, internet, calls, etc). Could you provide what kind of issue are did you experimented?

Comment: You are asking for opinions. BT has worked for me for years now. To help we would need at least the make/model/chipset id of the nic you use. Maybe it is just a driver issue that needs to be corrected. Or it could indeed be a bug that needs reporting. A newer LTS should provide better support BUT all hardware alterations will tickle down to older releases :)

Comment: You only need to look at all the questions posted right here about Bluetooth and 20.04 to see that (a) there is a big problem and (b) it isn't reproducible because it's environment- and history-dependent.  There are many dialogues of the form "here is what worked for me" followed both by "it worked for me too" and "but it didn't work for me". For instance, some have reported that a  cold start fixed it; others (including me) found that a cold start didn't help. The answer is probably to move to either 20.04.3 or 21.10; my question is which of those two is preferable.

Comment: Linux had problems with bluetooth and wifi because of hardware support in that area. So this is hardware related anyway and providing details is crucial. Asking so general a question is offtopic, non-constructive, and based on the assumption that many users have the same problem as you. My answer to your Q is YES, most bluetooth problems for most people are solved in 20,04. But so was the case with wifi in 18.04, only *mine* didn't work too well then. So, you are askiong for opinions, as Rinzwind said. If you do have problems try latest Kubuntu or wait for 22.04 which is coming in April 2022.

Answer (score 2):

You should [download](https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/) a live USB.  Boot from that USB and test your bluetooth device(s) to see if they operate to your satisfaction.

Comment: I've installed Kubuntu 21.10 and Bluetooth is working for me now. But I can't vouch for any other configuration, or even for 21.10 on anyone else's system.  I'd like to believe that Kubuntu has finally gotten it right.